# Laravel Blade - How to check for @auth of any guard

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

In my application I am trying to add "admin" users as well as "normal" users.
In order to do this I have created an additional [admin Guard and UserProvider](https://jamesmcfadden.co.uk/custom-authentication-in-laravel-with-guards-and-user-service-providers). This seems to log the user in under the 'admin' guard rather than the default 'web' guard.
Now, in my base template, I am trying to decide if the user is logged-in in order to decide if I should show the logout button.
To do this I am checking `@auth`. But this only seems to work if a "normal" user is logged in.
Is there a way to check if a user is logged in under *any* guard?

Answer (score 1):

You can check specific guards like this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade:

```
@auth('admin')
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth
```

But I'm not sure if something exists to check ANY guard.

I created the following for a recent project I worked on and really helped me to check who is logged in and if someone is logged in.

I added the following in to a `helpers.php`, using this guide http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/50/creating-a-helpers-file

```
if ( ! function_exists('logged_in')) {
function logged_in($guard = null)
{
        $validGuards = ['superadmin', 'admin', 'user'];

        // guard specified
        if ($guard) {

            // check if guard is valid
            if ( ! in_array($guard, $validGuards)) {
                return null;
            }

            return Auth::guard($guard)->check() ? $guard : null;
        }

        // no guard specified, check all guards
        foreach ($validGuards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return $guard;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

You can use this in your views or any where in your code like this

```
@if(logged_in('superadmin')) <-- returns guard name/null
    // logged in as super admin
@endif

@if(logged_in()) // <-- returns the guard name/null
    // logged in as any user
@endif
```

There might be a better way to do the above but it worked for me and was super helpful to use in views

--

I also created the following to get you the user who is logged in:

```
if ( ! function_exists('logged_in_user')) {
    function logged_in_user($guard = null)
    {
        if($guard) {
            return Auth::guard($guard)->check() ? Auth::guard($guard)->user() : null;
        }

        if(logged_in()) {
            return Auth::guard(logged_in())->check() ? Auth::guard(logged_in())->user() : null
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I used this alongside the above function

```
@if(logged_in('superadmin'))
    {{ logged_in_user()->name }}
@endif

@if(logged_in())
    {{ logged_in_user()->email }}
@endif
```

Again, there may be a better way to do this, but it worked for me

Comment: I feared that something like this would be required. It seems a bit hacky. Guards seem so useful to create admin users, but now it's so difficult to see if a user is logged in.
Maybe the documentation needs to be a bit clear on how to create an admin guard.

Comment: @Votemike yeah I was surprised when I couldn't find anything myself when trying to check which guard was logged in. Guards are so useful and make it super easy to implement authentication and I think it would help to have a way to find out which guard the current user is logged in to

Answer (score 1):

You can check the logged in guards in your blade like so:

```
 @if(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
//Do Admin stuff here
@elseif(Auth::guard('web')->check())
//Do Normal user stuff here
@endif
```